# How to define an TypeScript interface of an function on a react class?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to save a referral to SectionList on `this.SectionList` within my MessageDialog. I have tried to define the interface to allow SectionList on line 31, but that has no effect. What should I do?

TypeScript complains that:
`MessageDialog.tsx(132,38): error TS2339: Property 'SectionList' does not exist on type 'SkademeldingDialog'`

```
 29 interface IComponentProps {
 30   navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
 31   SectionList: any; // I tried to add SectionList here, but that did not work.
 32 }
 33
 34 interface IDispatchToProps {
 35   requestHendelsesvelger: RequestHendelsesvelgerInterface;
 36   requestProsessguide: RequestProsessguideInterface;
 37 }
 38
 39 type Props = IComponentProps & IDispatchToProps;

121 class MessageDialog extends React.Component<Props> {

128   public render() {
129
130     return (
131       <SectionList
132         ref={(sectionlist) => { this.SectionList = sectionlist; }}
137       >
138       </SectionList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Props` type is to type `this.props` in your component not the component instance itself, you shouldn't add the `SectionList` there. It should be a property on the class, that way it will exist on the `MessageDialog` type:

```
class MessageDialog extends React.Component<Props> {
  private sectionList: SectionList;
  public render() {

    return (
      <SectionList
        ref={(sectionlist) => { this.sectionList = sectionlist; }}
      >
      </SectionList>
```

Comment: That did almost work! :-) `MessageDialog.tsx(127,24): error TS2314: Generic type 'SectionList' requires 1 type argument(s).`. If I do `private sectionList: any`, then I get no warnings. Any idea how I can get the type correct?

Comment: I'll try to add DefinitelyTyped. Looks like it has typing for SectionList.

Comment: You would have to add the correct type args, Without seeing SectionList I cant say what they would be. eg `private sectionList: SectionList<Type>`